# Identify names starting with punctuation

Tags: python, pandas, string

To check if a row starts with punctuation, I was thinking of the use of string.punctuation and string.startswith. But when I do

```
df['start_with_punct']=df['name'].str.startswith(string.punctuation)
```

I get False when the names actually start with punctuation.

Example of data is

```
Name       
_faerrar_
!gfaherr_!£
nafjetes_
```

Expected output

```
Name            start_with_punct
_faerrar_           True
!gfaherr_!£         True
nafjetes_           False
```

I would need to understand how to get the right output as I would need also to test this with names starting with capital letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tuple` for pass multiple values to [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df['start_with_punct']=df['Name'].str.startswith(tuple(string.punctuation))
print (df)
         Name  start_with_punct
0   _faerrar_              True
1  !gfaherr_!              True
2   nafjetes_             False
```

For testing if first value is uppercase use [`Series.str.isupper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isupper.html) with indexing `str[0]`:

```
df['start_with_upper']=df['Name'].str[0].str.isupper()
print (df)
         Name  start_with_upper
0    Aaerrar_              True
1  dgfaherr_!             False
2   Nafjetes_              True
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I did not think of using tuple to fix the issue. In case of any capital word within the name, should I remove str[0] only?

Comment: @Val - yes, only remove `str[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) as match is by default anchored to the start of the string:

```
import re
regex = '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)
df['start_with_punct'] = df['Name'].str.match(regex)
```

output:

```
          Name  start_with_punct
0    _faerrar_              True
1  !gfaherr_!£              True
2    nafjetes_             False
```